# In-App Purchase not working on iOS 7

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, ios7, in-app-billing, skproduct

In App Purchases are not working for iOS 7!!!

For both the cases. 
1) Apps that I develop. they are working fine on iOS 6 not on iOS 7
2) Third Party Apps like "Glu Games'  Deer Hunter" the in App is working on iOS 6 but not on iOS 7

Code wise in iOS 7 the call back response delegate function

`- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response`

is never called in iOS 7

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the issue by restarting my iOS 7 device. Never faced anything like this before on iOS

x-(  Not another PC